# Nodejs: Expressjs and Restify structure

Tags: node.js, express, restify

I planned to design a web app that provides apis and web site, this is because the app can be used with mobile.

I'm currently using node-restify to provide the api, but now I need a way to serve dynamic pages of the app.

My initial idea was to use just ExpressJS to provide pages and APIs but I've read node-restify is much faster. Now my problem is that with restify I cannot serve html pages rendered in ejs.

Is there a way to have one app only and integrate express with restify.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting what you've written here, because according to this benchmark (16th March 2012):

http://blog.perfectapi.com/2012/benchmarking-apis-using-perfectapi-vs-express.js-vs-restify.js/

Restify is **a lot** slower then Express.

Express can easily handle ~1500 requests per second while Restify only ~250 per second.

But even if they already improved Restify I doubt that it can be faster then Express which is already extremely fast. Not to mention that it is entire framework with very useful other tools.

Concluding: use Express.js.

Comment: I have read that they have fixed Restify performance problems (also noted in the link you gave). Now it outperforms Express in almost all cases. What's more, a new version is in development which is promised to be 2x faster than the current version. That is quite reasonable. Express has a bit different purpose and so requires / includes more features. Every feature slows things down.

Comment: @Pius Yeah, might be true. On the other hand in most cases database is the bottleneck, so in the end it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for api:

https://github.com/rahpal/RestOnNode

RESTful framework on NodeJS

This project is build using the same project archutecture which is followed by ASP.Net WebApi 2.0. That means it will be having controllers, authentication mechanism etc. to start with. All you need to do is create your own controllers.